# Flexbox lay-out stacked columns and rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

#### Lay-out question

Not a bug or issue, but need some help.

I've been trying hard to get the following lay-out:

> > ***** DESKTOP *******
> >
> > [ <--BACK-- ]
> >
> > [----------------- HEADER -----------------]
> >
> > [-- META DATA --]  [ -------  IMAGE ------ ]
> >
> > [-- TAG DATA --]   [ ------- SUMMARY ----- ]
> >
> > ```
> >                [ ------- CONTENT ------
> >
> >                  ------- CONTENT ------
> >
> >                  ------- CONTENT ------
> >
> >                  ------- CONTENT ------
> >
> >                  ------- CONTENT ------
> >
> >                  ------- CONTENT ------]
> > ```
> >
> > ******* MOBILE *********
> >
> > [------- HEADER ------]
> >
> > [ ------  IMAGE ----- ]
> >
> > [ ----- SUMMARY ----- ]
> >
> > [-- TAG DATA --]
> >
> > [ ------ CONTENT -----
> >
> > ------- CONTENT -----
> >
> > ------- CONTENT -----
> >
> > ------- CONTENT -----
> >
> > ------- CONTENT -----
> >
> > ------- CONTENT -----]

#### Steps to Reproduce

```
<article>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
   back button
  </div>
  <div class=col-10>
   <header><h1 class=text-center>{$page_title}</h1></header>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="col-auto text-small">
    Date: <em>{$entry->postdate|cms_date_format}</em>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto text-small">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-auto">
      Category: 
     </div>
     <span class="text-secondary">
      {$tags|substr:0:-2} 
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto text-small">
    Author: <em>{$entry->author}</em>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto text-small">
    {svg use="bubbles"}
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
   Image
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
   Content
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   Category
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</article>
```

#### Additional info

- Shoelace version: Latest version
- Affected browsers: Safari

Thanks for your help!